# Converting multiple rows of data to a single column of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a basic excel spreadsheet with columns of data that needs to be exported as a single column of data.  I've been cutting and pasting/transposing the rows, but it's tedious.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Results should go across first each row.

Sample data below:

```
4619980.95  1040503.25  823644.03   1039799.69  1033153.29
9925740.32  2235456.21  1769547.72  2233944.65  2219665.26
7868405.05  1772107.1   1402768.74  1770908.85  1759589.19
2707020.09  609669.87   482603.92   609257.63   605363.25
4331232.14  975471.8    772166.28   974812.21   968581.21
4186857.73  942956.07   746427.4    942318.47   936295.17
7363094.64  1658302.06  1312682.67  1657180.76  1646588.05
4764355.35  1073018.98  849382.91   1072293.43  1065439.33
```

Comment: Is there always 5 columns?

Comment: No, it varies. Could be as small as 2 and sometimes as many as 8 or more.

Comment: Assume that data is stored at the first 8 columns `A:H`, then you can use a [`CONCATENATE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) function to concatenate them into a single row, e.g. in Excel of EN-US version, you can do  `=CONCATENATE(A1, ",", B1, ",", C1, ",", D1, ",", E1, ",", F1, ",", G1, ",", H1)`. And apply it into all the target range.

Comment: No, I don't want to CONCATENATE, I want the values in A1, B1, C1, D1 and E1 to become the values in A1, A2, A3, A4 and A5 and so forth.  All the data in the table above will become one long column of values in column A, going down the page.

Comment: If my answer worked please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a formula answer use INDEX():

```
=INDEX(A:XX,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/MATCH(1E+99,$1:$1))+1,MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,MATCH(1E+99,$1:$1))+1)
```

As this formula is copy/dragged down it will reference the next cell to the right till it comes to the last cell. Then it will move down to the next row.

It does require that the number of columns in row 1 is the same as all the other rows.

[image]